# How to get enum value from string if value doesn't match

Tags: java, enums

I have enum:

```
public enum Enumz{
    FIRST_VALUE(0, "one"),
    SECOND_VALUE(1, "two"),
    THIRD_VALUE(2, "three")

    private int id;
    private String name;

}
```

How can I find enum value if my String value match with enum string name? For example: if I have `String = "two"` I need to get `ENUMZ.SECOND_VALUE`.

Comment: You could implement a get method within the enum, something like public Enumz getEnumzByName(String name). That method should do a comparison and return the Enumz for which the name equals the input name argument.

Comment: Your enum doesn't compile. There's a syntax error and a missing constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8 `stream` alternative to `for loop`

```
String serachValue = "two";
Enumz enumz = Arrays.stream(Enumz.values())
                     .filter(v -> serachValue.equalsIgnoreCase(v.name))
                     .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Good practice is always put it as a static method into the `ENUM` itself as explained by other @Sagar Gangwal.

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum Enumz {
    FIRST_VALUE(0, "one"),
    SECOND_VALUE(1, "two"),
    THIRD_VALUE(2, "three");

    private int id;
    private String name;

    Enumz(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Enumz fromString(String text) {
        for (Enumz b : Enumz.values()) {
            if (b.name.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
class Sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Enumz.fromString("two"));
    }
}
```

You can implement your own method inside enum and call that method every time you want enum using String.

Above code will printing an output as below

### **`OUTPUT`**

**`SECOND_VALUE`**

Comment: I would modify the `fromString()` to `EnumSet.allOf(Enumz.class).stream().filter(enumz -> name.equals(enumz.name)).findAny().orElse(null)`. That you use the `EnumSet` class and `Stream`.